# The document at the url https://Myhost.com/WcfServices/MyService.svc was not recognized as a known document type

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, utf-8, wsdl

We have a load balance server which directs client requests to one of the 2 underlying servers where a tiny wcf service is hosted under IIS 8, Windows 2012.

Clients "**out side of our company's network**" gets an exception "ONLY" when they try to "Add Service Reference" in a .NET client to a wcf service. The request is secure over HTTPS.

Adding a reference succeeds on company's network and Also, When browsed the same service's URL (https://myhost.com/WcfServices/MyService.svc?WSDL) in the browser outside company's network, it doesn't give any exception and shows the contract of the service as usual..

Here is the exception when they try to add a reference.

The document at the url https://myhost.com/WcfServices/MyService.svc was not recognized as a known document type.
The error message from each known type may help you fix the problem:
- Report from 'XML Schema' is 'The document format is not recognized (the content type is 'text/html; charset=UTF-8').'.
- Report from 'https://myhost.com/WcfServices/MyService.svc' is 'The document format is not recognized (the content type is 'text/html; charset=UTF-8').'.
- Report from 'DISCO Document' is 'DTD is prohibited in this XML document.'.
- Report from 'WSDL Document' is 'The document format is not recognized (the content type is 'text/html; charset=UTF-8').'.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'https://myhost.com/WcfServices/MyService.svc'.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'https://myhost.com/WcfServices/MyService.svc'.
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.

here is how my web.config file looks like..

```
    <system.serviceModel>
<diagnostics performanceCounters="All" />
      <service behaviorConfiguration="WcfServices.MyServiceBehavior"
    name="WcfServices.MyService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WcfServices.IMyService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="WcfServices.Service1Behavior">
      <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="1000" maxConcurrentSessions="1000"
        maxConcurrentInstances="1000" />
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="WcfServices.MyServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="LargeSizeMessages"
             maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas
       maxDepth="32"
       maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
       maxArrayLength="2147483647"
       maxBytesPerRead="4096"
       maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

I've spent countless hours and tried a bunch of suggestions found on internet... unfortunately none has resolved this issue. What's wrong here ? Any help is highly appreciated !!!

Comment: Your company isn't using self-signed certificates, is it? Can you retrieve the full WSDL (via browser: https://myhost.com/WcfServices/MyService.svc?WSDL) from within your corporate network and from the outside? Then compare the two files by making a diff. I can very well imagine these files being different.

Comment: company is using the wild card certificate.if they are different, what does it indicate ?